# When Does A New Month Begin

Tags: rosh-chodesh-new-month

Does the new month begin the night when HaChodesh is seen, or does it begin next day (daybreak) after it is seen?

Comment: In the Hebrew calendar they are both the same. The night comes before the day

Comment: @Chatzkel That's not obviously the case here. Plausibly the night is day 30 and only from when the moon is seen or court declares the new month or something does it become the new month.

Comment: @DoubleAA are you saying that the first of the month starts in the middle of the day???? Of course not. Once the court declares it, it is effective retroactive to the night before. The calendar day always starts at night

Comment: @Chatzkel I'm saying that's a reasonable question. Just because you know it's not how we paskin doesn't make it a bad question. Hence the general rule you brought that night precedes day is insufficient to answer this question.

Answer (score -1):

It begins when the new moon is first seen by witnesses and beis Din has in time received and accepted those witnesses with enough time left for beis Din to say מקודש מקודש before night fall. See mishnayos Rosh hashana

Comment: This is not very precise